# Pandas: Irregular extracted dataframe.colums from "tsv" file with guessed delimiter

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `open_csv` call for opening a csv with an **unknown** delimiter:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv(
    instance.file_entity.path,
    engine='python',
    comment='#',
    skipinitialspace=True,
    skip_blank_lines=True,
    error_bad_lines=False,
    warn_bad_lines=True
)
```

However, `datafram.columns` gives me the following:

```
Index(['_RAJ2000;_DEJ2000;CXO;RAJ2000;DEJ2000;ePos;S/N;Fb;b_Fb;B_Fb;Fw;hr2;hr1;fc;fe;fs;Vab;Vib;Vaw;Viw'], dtype='object')
```

I was wondering why this is? I assumed the above would guess the delimiter, in this case ";", and then extract the columns correctly?

It seems like to me the engine is guessing at a comma and not semi-colon...

Any pointers would be greatly welcome!

Comment: Your file is not `tsv`, i.e. tab separated value, but rather `;`-separated-value? try passing `sep=';'` to `read_csv`.

Comment: @QuangHoang I have an unknown delimiter....I need to guess the delimiter?

Comment: It seems like to me the engine is guessing at a comma and not semi-colon...

Comment: That's what `csv` means: **comma separated-values**, the default delimiter is `,`. You need to specify with either `sep` or `delimiter` otherwise.

Comment: @QuangHoang I think we're crossing wires here and there - I *won't* know the delimiter for the csv ... although csv means comma-separated values, the delimiter can be different from an actual comma. Hence, why I need to guess the delimiter...